# What is the definition of a "large binary file"?

Tags: android, binaryfiles, android-sqlite, android-file, android-backup-service

According to the Android reference page, [FileBackupHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/FileBackupHelper.html) should "be used only with small configuration files, not large binary files."

I managed to successfully backup a database file of 8 kilobytes, but I'm curious at what point a file becomes a "large" binary file. Do you think Android is referring to files in the megabyte range?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an exact answer to that. Certainly 10s of KB would be considered "small" and perhaps even 100s KB in the greater scheme of things. If you look at general device capabilities, however, I suspect once you get to mega-bytes, you're probably looking at what might be considered "large".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no hardcoded limit in Android source code (which defines "large" vs "small"). At least, I didn't find within 10 minutes looking through Android source.

Generally speaking, you should take into consideration a speed of wireless connection. It depends a lot on where you and your users are located. If it's major cities with 3G/4G coverage - I think you can backup a megabyte, if's rural area and your users are charged per kilobyte, I would rather scale back to dozens of kilobytes.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts...getting a second opinion eased my concern